# Write address in a full sentence

Tags: expressions

How do I write address properly in a full sentence?

Ex) I am Michael Jordan who is living on 111 street at ABC district in Chicago in Illinois in the U.S..

Can I repeatedly use “in” there? 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Treat the address as a noun phrase, with comma separation.

> "He lives at 123 Some Street, Anytown, Chicago, Illinois"

No need to include the country unless you really don't think the person addressed knows where Chicago, Illinois is. If so, you can put it as a separate sentence - "That's in America".

If, however, you're literally dictating an address that someone else is to write down, and you expect them to be sending something to it from outside the US, it would be appropriate to add ", USA" to the end of that sentence. You might also put a colon after the 'at'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying a name of the city, and then the state or country, I think you don't have to say in (city) in (state/country). I think you can just say I live in Chicago, Illinois. If it is a very known place you don't need to add the country.

Comment: How about unknown place like my birthplace? I am Joung Kim who was born on 111 street in/at Donggu District in Busan in Korea